# can't detect div offset in IE7

Tags: jquery, css

```
$("#listPanels a").live("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        can_changePn = false;
        var tt = $(this).attr("href");
        var pos = $(tt).offset().top;
        var ctop = $('#contentPanel').scrollTop();
        alert(tt+" : "+pos+" : "+ctop);
        $('#contentPanel').animate({
            scrollTop: (ctop+pos-50)},
        500,function(){
            can_changePn = true;
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I use the above code to scroll to a div and it does work well in all browsers, however in IE7, it seems the code cannot get past `$(tt).offset().top;`, I have no clue as to what the problem might be, I did also try to use `position` instead of `offset` though, and the result is the same, if I try to `alert` that line, the alert doesn't even open. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting the offset of an attribute now. I think you want to change this:

```
var tt = $(this).attr("href");         
var pos = $(tt).offset().top;
```

to this:

```
var tt = $(this).attr("href");         
var pos = $(this).offset().top;
```

Comment: No, the attribute is actually a div's id, and I am trying to find out the offset of that div. But thanks to you I am a bit closer to the problem now, it seems, in all other browsers, the id ex:`#panel_00`, is returned, while IE7 seems to return to full URL not just the id, so nothing is found